# BigDecimal, division & MathContext - very strange behaviour

Tags: bigdecimal, java

CentOs 5.4, 
OpenJDK  Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-b09)

```
MathContext context = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);  
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("200.0", context);

BigDecimal goodPrice = total.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println("divided price=" + goodPrice.toPlainString());
// prints 66.66

BigDecimal goodPrice2 = total.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), new MathContext(2,    RoundingMode.FLOOR));
System.out.println("divided price2=" + goodPrice2.toPlainString());
// prints 66
```

BUG ?

Comment: Same results on 64bit Sun JDK 1.6.0_18 on Windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javadoc for the first situation:

> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this / divisor), 
>   and whose scale is as specified. If rounding must be performed to generate a result with the specified scale, the specified rounding mode is applied.

and the Javadoc for the second situation:

> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this / divisor), 
>   with rounding according to the context settings.

referring to the javadoc for MathContext we get:

> Immutable objects which encapsulate
>   the context  settings which describe
>   certain rules for numerical operators,
>   such as those implemented by the
>   BigDecimal class. 
>   The base-independent
>   settings are: precision: the number of
>   digits to be used for an operation;
>   results are rounded to this precision
>   roundingMode: a RoundingMode object
>   which specifies the algorithm to be
>   used for rounding.

So in the first case, you specified a SCALE of 2, meaning that you round to 2 decimal places of accuracy, where the rounding is performed as a floor function. The second calculation has a specified PRECISION of 2, which is rounded to two digits of accuracy, where the rounding is a floor function. So, in the first case, you asked for 2 digits *after the decimal place*, and in the second, you just asked for 2 digits. If, for example, you had asked for 4 digits in your MathContext, you'd get 66.66 as you answer.

So I don't think that this is a bug so much as that the two methods don't perform the same calculation.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely the expected behavior. I think you make the mistake and mix rounding(scale) and precision.

```
total.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)
```

here you override your the MathContext and use a rounding.

```
total.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), new MathContext(2,    RoundingMode.FLOOR))
```

here you set a precision of 2 and receive only 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Javadoc for the divide(BigDecimal, MathContext) method, it seems that only the rounding mode of the context is taken into account.